# React.createClass vs extends Component

Tags: react-native

What's the different between

```
var MyClass = React.createClass({...});
```

To

```
class MyClass extends React.Component{...}
```

Comment: There's actually more differences than the `getInitialState` commented in the accepted answer. In addition the differences are about: use of `this`; use of `defaultProps`; use of _mixins_. You can read about those changes in this article: https://toddmotto.com/react-create-class-versus-component/

Answer (score 43, accepted):

These two ways depend on if you are using ES6 syntax or not, and they also change the way you set up your initial state.

When using ES6 classes, You should initialize state in the `constructor`.

When using React.createClass you have to use the `getInitialState` function.

**ES6 Class Syntax:**

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { /* initial state, this is ES6 syntax (classes) */ };
  }
}
```

**ES5 React.CreateClass syntax:**

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return { /* initial state */ };
  },
});
```

These will both work the same way to set up initial state.

Comment: With the Babel plugin **transform-class-properties** you can initialize your state outside the constructor using ES6 classes (actually, you don't need to use constructor, super, etc) and you don't need, therefore, to bind each custom method to the component in. This functionality is also included in Create-React-App. In order to use it you just have to script your custom methods with arrow functions (taking advantage of that they do not have their own this and, more importantly, of the JS Property Initializers ).

Answer (score 6):

With the `class MyClass extends React.Component{...}` syntax,

you can not use mixins and you need to bind the context of the method yourself

```
class MyClass extends Component {
   constructor() {
     super();
     this.handleClick.bind(this);
   }

   handleClick() {
     this.setState(...);
   }
}
```

to me these are the biggest differences.

to replace the mixin, you can use a Container to wrap your component

```
export default Container(MyClass);

function Container(Component) {
   var origin = Component.prototype.componentDidMount;
   Component.prototype.componentDidMount = function() {
      origin.apply(this, arguments);
      /* do mixin */
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

One major differentiator not mentioned above is how the `state` is inherited when using `createClass` vs `extending` a `Component`.

```
var BaseComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      foo: 'bar'
    };
  }
});

var BaseClass = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      foo: 'bar'
    };
  }
});

class Test extends BaseClass { // or extend BaseComponent
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ...this.state,
      myNewVar: 'myNewVal'
    }

  render() {
    alert(this.state.foo)
  }
}
```

Comment: what does this (createClass allows inheriting the state) lines means?

Comment: Inheritance is a very common OOP concept. You can read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)). It just means that although `Test` doesn't define `foo` on its `state`, it gets it from its parent when it extends `BaseClass`.

Comment: note that this isn't idiomatic React - you should **only** extend `React.Component` when designing React classes (and ideally use functional components, if possible). Prefer composition to inheritance.

Comment: @Idefixx Can you expand on this please?

Comment: [This](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) sums it up well.

Comment: Yes, composition is definitely the way to go over inheritance. Although, in rare circumstances, inheritance does come in handy. I've updated the answer above to demonstrate both use cases.

Comment: It's unclear how you're instantiating the state object in Test that the derived `state` variable is still accessible and intact. Aren't you like overriding it cuz then I see you still be able to access `foo`?

Answer (score 3):

**React.createClass**

Here we have a const with a React class assigned, with the important render function following on to complete a typical base component definition.

```
import React from 'react';

const Contacts = React.createClass({
    render() {
    return (
    <div></div>
   );
  }
});

export default Contacts;
```

**React.Component**

Let’s take the above React.createClass definition and convert it to use an ES6 class.

```
import React from 'react';

class Contacts extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  }
    render() {
    return (
    <div></div>
  );
 }
}

export default Contacts;
```

From a JavaScript perspective we’re now using ES6 classes, typically this would be used with something like Babel to compile the ES6 to ES5 to work in other browsers. With this change, we introduce the **constructor**, where we need to call **super()** to pass the props to **React.Component**.

For the React changes, we now create a **class** called “Contacts” and **extend** from **React.Component** instead of accessing **React.createClass** directly, which uses less React boilerplate and more JavaScript. This is an important change to note further changes this syntax swap brings.

[More](https://toddmotto.com/react-create-class-versus-component/)