# declaring a react class the right way

Tags: reactjs

I found different ways of creating a class in React, what is the difference between a) and B) ?

A)

```
var Profile = React.createClass({...})
```

B)

```
class Profile extends React.Component {
```

Comment: A very nice article can be found here: https://daveceddia.com/react-es5-createclass-vs-es6-classes/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React.createClass vs extends Component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33526493/react-createclass-vs-extends-component)

Answer (score -2):

It's written in ReactJS document.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-es6.html