# How to make a wsdl service connection for react native

Tags: asp.net-mvc, react-native, wsdl

I started to learn react-native technolgy.I have a asp.net mvc project that I need to establish a WSDL service connection with react-native technology.I have given the codes in the link below, but it is not shown in which folder I will add these codes. Please help me.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap

Comment: Soap is a package that get added to your project  , like a library and you need to use it. above shared link also has example how to use it

Comment: I can't do because I don't know how to create classes and files that I need to create.

Comment: are you on react project or mvc project? . which editor you are using

Comment: I'm doing react-native work in visual studio code editor

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33526493/react-createclass-vs-extends-component